# How do I fix my SSL certificates errors caused by my organization VPN in Git?

Tags: git, ssl-certificate, certificate, vpn

Git is no longer working on my machine. Each action I do I get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/myproject/myrepo.git/': schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
```

I was already using:

```
git config --global http.sslBackend schannel
```

Also Firefox is throwing errors like this for all websites (strangely Chrome is OK):

```
Someone could be trying to impersonate the site and you should not continue.
 
Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust www.google.com because its certificate issuer is unknown, the certificate is self-signed, or the server is not sending the correct intermediate certificates.
 
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

And in Firefox I was already using `security.enterprise_roots.enabled = true` in `about:config`.

Both settings I changed 1+ years ago is because of my organization VPN (Cisco AnyConnect) and everything worked fine. I'm on Windows 10 Pro and I didn't change anything on my side. It just stopped working.

How can I fix those errors? (So far I do `git config http.sslVerify false` to get unstuck in Git but it's a bad solution).